# Can I create a PyPI release of a package, if I'm not its original author?

Tags: python, pip, packaging, pypi, python-packaging

I'm a collaborator of a certain open-source project on GitHub. The guy, who originally created the project, is busy with new activities and gave me a collaborator access, so that I can merge pull-requests to the repo etc.

Now it's time to create a new release at PyPI. Can I do a new release, or only the original author of the package can do that? I found a guide here: https://packaging.python.org/distributing/ and I'm trying to push a release to a [test PyPI site](https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=submit_form) via twine, but it won't allows me to push package forms.

Comment: No, I don't think you can. Otherwise anyone could just publish a malicious version of a popular package.

Comment: If it's already on PyPI and you want to update the version of the existing package, you need the credentials used to upload the package in the first place.

Comment: @AlexHall Yes, it is already on PyPI. So, there is only 1 set of credentials, which are personal credentials of package author and I have to ask him to create a release everytime I need to do so (or ask him to pass those credentials to me, which might not be safe, cause other packages, he created might be accessed with them as well).

Comment: See [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/packageindex.html).  It should be possible for the author to designate you as an "owner" if he wants to pass control of the project to you, or as a "maintainer" if just wants to authorize you to update the project on PyPI.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks a lot, your comment solved my problem. Can you post it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/packageindex.html) about how PyPI works.  They have a system for designating "owners" and "maintainers" of packages.  It should be possible for the author to designate you as an "owner" if he wants to pass control of the project to you, or as a "maintainer" if just wants to authorize you to update the project on PyPI.

Comment: 404. Maybe this is the new link: https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html